# iOS ASIHTTPRequest [request temporaryFileDownloadPath]; will download file and erase automatically?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am trying to check the response time with downloading some image file..
So I am using ASIHTTPRequest [request temporaryFileDownloadPath];

Will it download file in temp directory in iPhone and erase it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `temporaryFileDownloadPath` is where the file is placed during the download. After the download, it will be copied from there to the location of `downloadDestinationPath`. If you set `downloadDestinationPath` to `NSTemporaryDirectory()`, then the file will be erased by the system automatically at some point.

If you want to erase the file straight away though, just don't set a `downloadDestinationPath` or a `temporaryFileDownloadPath`, and it will be kept in memory and then deallocated when the request goes out of scope. If the image is too big to fit in memory, set a `downloadDestinationPath` somewhere (doesn't really matter, as long as it's valid), and then after the download is finished remove the file from disk using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[request downloadDestinationPath] error:nil]`. Pass in an `NSError*` to the `error` parameter to check if the delete encounters an error.

Comment: Do you know what's gonna happen if I just use [request temporaryFileDownloadPath]; ? It seems it's working ok..

Comment: Well, I had to look at the code, but if `![self downloadDestinationPath]` (if you haven't set a download path), it doesn't save to the temporary file even if the temporary path is set.

Comment: Does it mean that it's downloaded and not saved anywhere?

Comment: This line of code runs ok without any problem  [request temporaryFileDownloadPath];  If it doesn't save the file in local directory, that might be what I want.. But difficult to see how request works in the case..

Comment: The way it works in this case is, it downloads the file into the `RAM` of the iPhone (NOT onto the disk), and in all other cases the file would be written piece by piece to the disk as it's downloaded, but in this case that step just doesn't happen, so what you get at the end is your whole file still in `RAM`. And then it just clears the `RAM` for that file.